# SQL query to fillter and update table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have an employee database table with a column NAME

in the NAME field we have names of employees like this -> LI-MING (ALLEN)

this is there real first name and there English nick name in ()

i would like to know if i can swap this around in an SQL UPDATE query

FROM: LI-MING (ALLEN) TO: ALLEN (LI-MING)

the reason why i would like this is Users want to have it sort this column by nick name

Comment: What about building a new NAME field by selecting a substring inside parenthesis? I've never used sql-server but this looks like a good starting point: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx

Comment: You can sort it already by nickname without swapping it around: build a regex returning the nickname and order by that. -- Also, your situation suggests that you rather store the English name in a separate column, instead of in the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    UPDATE Employee
    SET NAME = 
        SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX('(',name)+1,(CHARINDEX(')',name)-CHARINDEX('(',name)-1))+
        ' ('+SUBSTRING(name,1,CHARINDEX('(',name)-1)+')'
FROM Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would create seperate colums both for name and nick name. Trying to get a string portion on the fly prevent sql server from using indexes which might be really importand from performance perspective.

So there are basicly two options:

1. Parse values for seperate columns every time you update or insert a new employee (via TRIGGER, application code, etc).
2. Or just create two calculated columns but make sure they are marked as PERSISTED.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had worked on several project and I have done it my way to update same issue that you been through in 3 steps:

1) Create table with ID or Name field and Insert the values to the table

2) Trim the values with different functions and insert the final value to different table.

3) Update the old table with the new value

I don't say this is the only way to do thing but there might be other ways as well.

```
Create table #Employee(
EmployeeName varchar(200)
)

Insert into #Employee
Select 'LI-MING (ALLEN)' union all
Select 'Jio-Kio (Smith)'


Select 
substring(employeename,1,patindex('%(%',employeename)-1),
--Len(substring(employeename,1,patindex('%(%',employeename)-1)),
Right(employeename,len(employeename)-(len(substring(employeename,1,patindex('%(%',employeename)))))

 from #Employee

 Create table #EmployeeNew(
 Employeename1 varchar(200),
 Employeename2 varchar(200)
 )

 Insert into #EmployeeNew(Employeename1, Employeename2)

Select 
ltrim(rtrim(substring(employeename,1,patindex('%(%',employeename)-1))),
ltrim(rtrim(Right(Employeename,charindex('(',employeename,1)-3)))
 from #Employee

 Select * from #Employee
 Select * from #EmployeeNew
 Select cast('('+Employeename1+')'+left(employeename2,len(employeename2)-1) as varchar(200)) from #EmployeeNew

Update e
Set e.EmployeeName = cast('('+e1.Employeename1+')'+left(e1.employeename2,len(e1.employeename2)-1) as varchar(200))
from #Employee e
left outer join #EmployeeNew e1 on ltrim(rtrim(substring(e.employeename,1,patindex('%(%',e.employeename)-1))) =e1.Employeename1
```